# JSON.NET string to JSON Javascript

Tags: jquery, json.net

I've decided to use JSON.Net to convert my Date/Time objects into the string new Date(ticks). I was going to use jQuery's $.parseJSON to turn the date string into an object but it throws an exception saying that the string is invalid JSON.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

Comment: Not quite. This JSON.net converts the date time object to a usable javascript format already. Just trying to find out if there are any other JS JSON parsers that will handle a string with the new Date(233123) format.

Comment: I think if you read it again, you'll see that it is a duplicate.  I think MS is looking for you to eval() the date string, which is just dumb and dangerous.  Again, your best bet is to bypass their serializer and craft it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

MS dropped the ball on that one.  I've run into this myself.

The best bet is to get the underlying core value (integer) and pass that through.  You'll need to do specific formatting on it to turn it into a date on the client-side however, but it is as simple as making a new Date(data.json_net_date);

Answer (score 0):

Failing to see how the EVAL will affect security in this situation since I am the one sending a uniform string created from a DB DateTime field.