# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to JsonDate format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

How can I convert a date value in "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format to "/Date(1324414956395)/" format (Json Date).

I am passing the date format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" into a MVC controller action method and I need to compare that to another date in JsonDate format in the code.
Thanks for help.

Comment: It isn't JSONDate, it is a timestamp !

Comment: See the answer by Jeff Meatball Yang: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: @Bakudan-ханювиги okay.. I am storing the time stamp in Json document in that case. Do you know how I can convert mm/dd/yyyy into that timestamp format?

Comment: @keyboardP That link talks about converting TimeStamp "/Date(1324414956395)/" into mm/dd/yyyy .. I want the other way round.Please read original post. Thank you

Comment: @ZVenue - Jeff Meatball Yang's method takes in a DateTime object (as an extension method) and converts it to a double. It is not converting from a double to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6196/discussion-between-zvenue-and-keyboardp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dt.ToUniversalTime()` won't be recognised when using `DateTime?`. `DateTime?` is essentially `Nullable<DateTime>`. What you need to do is use the `Value` property to retrieve the `DateTime` object

```
 dt.Value.ToUniversalTime();
```

You can then use the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json) (Jeff Meatball Yang's answer, not the accepted answer) with your nullable DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;

Or

This superior solution from this link:  [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
```

It seems that this is a bad way to compare dates, however.  This is basically counting the ticks since 1970 (or something) and is going to be a pretty long and accurate number.  Even if you needed to make certain that the dates matched down to a second it seems like it would be easier to convert all the universal time to mm/dd/yyyy format and then compare at that point.

Comment: But JavaScript timestamps have an epoch of 01/01/1970. This won't work unless you subtract that offset from `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @Chase: How do I do this for a specific date .. not for "Now"

Comment: @JimMischel - Right you are.  You can offset it with the actual 1970 value or the solution that I linked from the other person which is much more readable.

Comment: @Chase I cannot get dt.ToUniversalTime() recognized.. I have "using system" namespace.