# Parse .NET date with Javascript

Tags: jquery, .net, json

This is the value of my variable:

```
date.dateFrom = /Date(1328137200000)/
```

Here is how I use it:

```
$('#txtBoxDateFrom').val(data.dateFrom);
```

How to convert it to "normal" look?
I consider normal look this: 01/01/2012

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: what's JSON got to do with it?

Comment: And this: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Comment: is `date.dateFrom` and `data.dateFrom` somehow related?

Comment: What is the type of the value that you try to describe? It looks like a regular expression literal, but that wouldn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function FormatDate(d)
{
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

var formatted = FormatDate(new Date(1328137200000));
// Sets it as 2/2/2012
```

If you want to pad it with zeros:

```
function FormatDate(d)
{
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  return (month <= 9 ? '0'+month : month) + "/" + (day <= 9 ? '0'+day : day) + "/" + year;
}

var formatted = FormatDate(new Date(1328137200000));
// Sets it as 02/02/2012
```

Comment: but FormatDate (your function) always returns 3/19, even when the date is not that.

Comment: @Srcee I had a var d = new Date() in there as I was testing it. I updated it now and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Date.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) or some other related method ([`toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString), [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), etc), depending on what you consider "normal" look.