# javascript regular expression to parse a .net json Datetime

Tags: javascript, regex, json, date

I'm no regular expression guru, so I'm asking for help to come out with a regular expression that would work like this:

```
var regExp = ???

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0800)\/') = [..., '1330848000000', '0800']

// optional gmt
regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000)\/') = [..., '1330848000000', null]

regExp.exec('\/Date(1)\/') = [..., '1', null]

// gmt required if - is present
regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-)\/') = null

// escaping backslash is required
regExp.exec('/Date(1330848000000-0800)\/') = null
regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0800)/') = null

// case sensitive
regExp.exec('\/date(1330848000000-0800)\/') = null

// only numbers allowed
regExp.exec('\/Date(1aaa848000000-0800)\/') = null
regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0a00)\/') = null
```

I got stuck pretty early with something as stupid as this:

```
/\\bla(.*)bla/.exec('\bla123bla') = null // instead of [ ..., '123']

new RegExp('\\\\bla(.*)bla').exec('\bla123bla') = null // instead of [ ..., '123']
```

Comment: You seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: "Escaping backslash is required" - Actually, with or without the backslash, the 2 strings are exactly the same, since `/` doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Yes, I did realize that playing with chrome debugger, but .Net spec requires it, and I'd like to enforce it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex if the string never contains any other numbers apart from the time and the time zone:

```
/(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/
```

Putting into your code:

```
var regex = /(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?/;
// regex.exec...
```

If you really need to *validate* **and** extract the numbers out of the string:

```
/^\/Date\((\d+)(?:-(\d+))?\)\/$/
```

The regex above will check that the string follows the exact format, and also extract the numbers out.

Comment: I got EXACTLY to the same answer! (honest, no cheating), but you came first... So I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

The following regex checks for your required constraints:

```
\\/Date\((\d{13})(-(\d{4}))?\)\\/
```

It checks for a `\` followed by a `/` followed by the text `Date` followed by brackets enclosing 13 digits and an optional sequence of `-` followed by 4 digits, then a required `\` and `/`.

The `\\` matches a single `\` which requires escaping as it is a special character in regex. Same is in the case of `(` and `)`.

From this, $1 matches the 13 digits inside the brackets and $3 matches the 4 digits if present.

Comment: Could you provide the whole javascript sentence? I tried with: new RegExp('\\\\/Date\\((\\d{13})(-(\\d{4}))?\\)\\\\/').exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0800)\/') and it gives me null

Comment: I have only a little knowledge in javascript. Let me try.

Comment: Thanks Naveed, I do understand your reasoning, but I seem to be having troubles escaping slashes, I guess...

Comment: I think `\\\\/Date\\((\\d{13})(-(\\d{4}))?\\)\\\\/` is what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with regular expressions and finally got it

The escaping slashes are just being ignored by javascript, so this it the solution I came out with (tested on chrome console)

```
var regExp
undefined

regExp = /^\/Date\((\d+)(?:-(\d+))?\)\/$/
/^\/Date\((\d+)(?:-(\d+))?\)\/$/

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0800)\/')
["/Date(1330848000000-0800)/", "1330848000000", "0800"]

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000)\/')
["/Date(1330848000000)/", "1330848000000", undefined]

regExp.exec('\/Date(1)\/')
["/Date(1)/", "1", undefined]

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-)\/')
null

regExp.exec('/Date(1330848000000-0800)\/')
["/Date(1330848000000-0800)/", "1330848000000", "0800"]

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0800)/')
["/Date(1330848000000-0800)/", "1330848000000", "0800"]

regExp.exec('\/date(1330848000000-0800)\/')
null

regExp.exec('\/Date(1aaa848000000-0800)\/')
null

regExp.exec('\/Date(1330848000000-0a00)\/')
null
```