# Is there any way to change date time formatting in JSON?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime

I'm using JSON to send data to client. However, the date fields get transformed into a timespan format like `/Date(1363807800000)/`.

Is there anyway to get rid of it and let server send `DateTime` values like `2013/7/21 3:44 PM` to client?

Comment: what's wrong with JSON fmt?

Comment: What server programming language are you using?

Comment: We use C# for server-side language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: What problem are you getting with this? Where do you want to use it? JQuery?

Comment: Have a look at Perishable Dave's answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format. It should be what you're looking for.

Comment: If using JQuery this should help  var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));

Comment: i'm using angularJS, i want to use 2 way binding for date value in an input so user can change it.

Comment: @EhsanUllah: That code has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. And it looks like you just copied that code from the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this,

```
var data = "/Date(1363807800000)/"; 
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
var result = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1) : date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate()) + " " + (date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ":" + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes());
```

Then, use this RegEx to validate it,

```
/ ^ \ d {4} - \ d { 2} - \e{2} \e{2}：\e{2}：\e{2} $ /
```

Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Json.NET (you can install it via NuGet):

```
object testObject = new { Name = "TestName", DateTime = DateTime.Now };
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
Console.Write(output);
```

Output:

> "{\"Name\":\"TestName\",\"DateTime\":\"2013-07-21T15:01:56.2872469+03:00\"}"

In case ISO DateTime format does not work well for you, you can write your own DateTimeConverter to use with SerializeObject function.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote once this, maybe you could add the string to your json ?

```
var getDate = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var prefix = "["
        + date.getDate() + "."
        + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "."
        + date.getFullYear() + " "
        + date.toString().split(" ")[4]
        + "]";
    return prefix;
};
```