# JSON key as time

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've a json file in my ajax request, the ajax file is loaded, i know posible that my apologies for that.

i have a json file:

```
{
"message": {
    "1376819020": {
        "id": "151",
        "text": "Waar ? :)",
        "time": "1376819020",
        "fullname": "David"
    },
    "1376985491": {
        "id": "152",
        "text": "feff",
        "time": "1376985491",
        "fullname": "David"
    }
}
```

}

If i remove the time stamps ( 1376985491, 1376819020 ) i can load the json file into javascript but if i let the timestamps then i cant load because the numbers are random.

has any one a idea how i can load it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cant load because the numbers are random."?

Comment: Do you mean you can't access the values because you don't know what the keys (timestamps) are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

Comment: you can easily iterate then with something like `for (i in obj.message) { ... }` if you have to.

Comment: i mean that i cant load the json file further because the timestamp is random.

Comment: @David the problem is that "can't load the JSON file" doesn't really mean anything. It's proper JSON, so it **is** possible to work with the string as JSON, and a JSON parser would be happy with it.

Comment: I understand is must be cant load the json file further, i know that it is proper json.

Comment: @David: I don't think "load" is the word you are looking for.  "Load" means to "download".  I'm assuming that part works fine.  The word you want is probably "traverse" or simply "read".

Comment: @RocketHazmat Perhaps you might be looking for "parse".

Comment: @JeffNoel: That too.  I assumed it was already parsed and he was just trying to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the data inside a specific object.

```
var json = {
  "message": {
    "1376819020": {
       "id": "151",
       "text": "Waar ? :)",
       "time": "1376819020",
       "fullname": "David Blokzijl"
    },
    "1376985491": {
       "id": "152",
       "text": "feff",
       "time": "1376985491",
       "fullname": "David Blokzijl"
    }
  }
};
```

Try accessing the property like `["1376985491"]` instead of `.1376985491`

```
alert(json.message["1376985491"].id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for..in` loop to iterate over the object keys:

```
var obj = {
    "message": {
        "1376819020": {},
        "1376985491": {}
    }
};

for(var timestamp in obj.message) {
    console.log(timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Okee i will try this.

Comment: this was the solution!

Comment: Just a quick note here: Wouldn't it be better to use a regular `for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(obj).length; i++)` loop, performance-wise? `for ... in` seems to hurt a lot on code execution time.

Comment: @JeffNoel Maybe, but Object.keys has support issues.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the numbers aren't random; They are milliseconds after epoch date.

You may find more information on how to convert them to valid javascript datetime [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json).

Comment: The numbers aren't random but not the same!

Comment: I understand, but it seems to me that your code is using timestamps as indexes. As Pointy and David properly pointed out, this is a valid JSON content; the problem lies within your interpreter code.