# json deserialization vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I need to deserialize this, which is encoded in JSON and I can not, I need it, anyone can help me?

```
[{"idReservation":2560,
"startDate":"30/09/2013 09:00",
"endDate":"30/09/2013 09:10",
"timeOut":"24/09/2013 16:02:23",
"idResource":1477,
"resourceDescription":"Profesional",
"players":
[{"idPlayer":283,
"idCustomer":2,
"name":"Ignacio",
"image":"/public/images/interface/customer/user.png",
"total":0}],
"anulable":true,
"name":"Ignacio",
"price":0,
"status":"Reservada",
"parententityname":"",
"idparententity":"",
"unixTime":1380524400},]
```

greetings and thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=JSON+deserializer+for+.net

Comment: @YuriyGalanter just add that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @YuriyGalanter suggests [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) will do the job, it has [great performance](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/04/25/json-net-5-0-release-4-performance) and avoids the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json) you get when trying to serialise a javascript datetime object to .net datetime object.

The [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Samples.htm#) provides [an example](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) of how to deserialise an object.

Comment: sorry but i don`t understand

Comment: @user2831658 download and reference the dll from your project and use the code in the provided documentation: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Samples.htm#

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mr Shoubs' answer:

1) Download the Json.Net DLL per Mr Shoubs' answer.

2) [Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) to this DLL in your Visual Studio Project.

[image]

3) Create a VB Reservation class that you want to end up with:

```
Public Class Reservation
    Public Property idReservation() as Integer
    Public Property startDate() as Date
    ...
End Class
```

Make the spelling and casing exactly as they are in the JSON object to keep things simple.

4) Declare an object of type Reservation and populate it with the JSON string you have - using the [DeserializeObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeObject.htm) method:

```
Dim obj As Reservation
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Reservation)(yourJsonString)
```

`obj` should now contain the data you want.