# How to set a datetime variable as mindate and maxdate in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

It retrieving date time 06/03/2014 12:00:00 AM and end date is 31/03/2015 12:00:00 AM but in my jquery alert message is showing like this /9413044200000/ i dontknow whats a problem i need to set min date and max date in datepicker pls some one help me. . .

My JsonResult

```
public JsonResult GroupName(string tourname, string MatchType)
    {                                   
        var sdate = entity.TblTournaments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Torname == tourname && x.Recordstatus == 1).TourStartdate;
        var edate = entity.TblTournaments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Torname == tourname && x.Recordstatus == 1).TourEnddate;
        var data = new { sdate, edate };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my jquery is

```
     $.post("/BindInventory/GroupName", { tourname: tname, MatchType: MatchType }, function (result) {                      
                   var startdate = result.sdate;
                   var enddate = result.edate;
                   alert(result.sdate);
                   $('#date').datepicker('option', 'minValue', new Date(startdate));
                   $('#date').datepicker('option', 'maxValue', new Date(enddate));
               }, "json");
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: If i use this code it will showing like this friend and datepicker value is also not set "Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse JSON - date with:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

*Source here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/1278667*

**EDIT**:
In your case:

```
$.post("/BindInventory/GroupName", { tourname: tname, MatchType: MatchType }, function (result) {                      
               var startdate = new Date(parseInt(result.sdate.substr(6)));
               var enddate = new Date(parseInt(result.edate.substr(6)));
               $('#date').datepicker('option', 'minValue', startdate);
               $('#date').datepicker('option', 'maxValue', enddate);
           }, "json");
```

Comment: If i use this code it will showing like this friend and datepicker value is also not set "Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"