# How to change the format of date that getting from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

how to change the format of date that getting from database[image]
getting date from database showing some error. please check the image

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: @ Matt Murdock alert shows the out put date format check my img

Comment: What about some code? Some hints? I mean, what format do u use in your db (timestamp or date?) And on which layer do u want to change the format?

Comment: @kannanD.S - Show us some code that you are currently using so that we can take it as a reference and help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

Comment: what is it? date in miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(yourDate.substr(6)));
```

to format your date use the following code

```
 var parsedDate= new Date(date); 
var formattedDate =parsedDate.getDate()+"-"+parsedDate.getMonth()+"-"+parsedDate..getFullYear();
```

Comment: @ Optimus thx i got a lond date format now, how to foramat that date to hour and minut

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, assuming you can manipulate the 'date' you are getting from the database:

```
d = yourdate();
new_d = d.toUTCString();
```

There are also `.toLocaleTimeString() (for times i.e., 11:11:12 am) and .toDateTimeString() (for days i.e., 11/11/2011)`