# How to convert MicrosoftDateFormat to DateTime c# using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert `MicrosoftDateFormat` to `DateTime` but not sure how to do that. I know how to do the opposite, meaning, convert `DateTime` to `MicrosoftDateFormat`. I tried following:

Approach-1:

```
var input = DateTime.Now;
var jsonMsDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
});
```

Output:

```
"\"\\/Date(1488389116170-0500)\\/\""
```

What I want is,

```
Input =  "/Date(1488393000000-0500)/"
Output = DateTime
```

Comment: SerializeObject = convert from object to JSON. You're *starting* with JSON, so you should be calling DeserializeObject. Although that's only judging by your final "input / output" part. Your code definitely starts with a DateTime, not a string, making the whole question very confusing.

Comment: Note that at least some of the backslashes in the output are probably what you're seeing in the debugger, and not part of the output. It's hard to say. A [mcve] would help...

Comment: Check out this SO post with 10 answers and 220 up votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry about the confusion. Based on your suggestion I have found the solution and posted it below. Thank you

Comment: @CSharper Mark the correct answer and upvote the value adding answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution:

```
public static void JsonToDateTime()
{
    var dateObj = new DateTest { Date = "/Date(1488393000000-0500)/" };
    var jsonDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateObj.Date);
    var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(jsonDate);

}

public class DateTest
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
3/1/2017 1:30:00 PM
```

Comment: No need to cast your object to <DateTime>, you get `System.DateTime` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize jsonMSDate, and just verify the type returned. Try following code:

```
 var datetime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMsDate);
 Console.WriteLine(datetime.GetType());
```

`datetime.GetType()` returns `System.DateTime` as required by you.