# Push DateTime to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, google-visualization

I want to push ASP.NET Model `DateTime` values into an array to be used within the Google Chart API. I get an error saying I'm missing an `')'` when I use the following:

```
    var dates = [];
    @foreach (var s in Model.Scores)
    {
        //it works fine here
        @:dates.push(parseFloat(@s.Score));
        //but causes an error here
        @:dates.push(new Date(@s.Date));
    }
```

I've also tried

```
@:dates.push(String(@s.Date));
```

and

```
@:dates.push(String(@s.Date.ToString()));
```

and

```
@:dates.push(String(@s.Date.Date));
```

When I pass it a number instead of a `DateTime` it works fine:

```
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Scores.Count(); i++)
    {
        @:count.push(@i);
    }
```

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that and I get the same error

Comment: what does the generated source look like? Also is `var dates` supposed to be a javascript variable or asp one?

Comment: @charlietfl `dates` is supposed to be JavaScript. The generated code looks shows a `DateTime` value pushed into the js array

Comment: OK but those Datetime outputs are not valid in javascript. You need to extract the timestamp from them. I'm assuming they look like `Date(2004005000)`

Comment: @charlietfl in this case they look like `Date(05/28/2018 12:00:00)` or thereabouts (I didn't copy directly). How do I get it to the format needed?