# How to prevent format change of date in view after save in ASP MVC

Tags: json, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

After saving `DateTime` in controller, I pass it back to the `View` but when it's displayed in view the value became `/Date(1545062400000)/`.

I already checked in the controller while in process if the data was changed but it did not since I'm just passing the `viewmodel` in the `view`.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateHeader(RecordViewModel recordViewModel)
    {
        var ResultMessage = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Record record = (from c in context.Records
                                           where c.RecordId == recordViewModel.RecordId
                                           select c).FirstOrDefault();
            if (record == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            record.Description = recordViewModel.Description;
            record.Date = recordViewModel.Date;
            record.Remarks = recordViewModel.Remarks;
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                ResultMessage = "Record successfully updated.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorHelper.GetInnerException(ex));
                ResultMessage = "Error: " + ErrorHelper.GetInnerException(ex);
            }
        }
        var result = new { Model = recordViewModel, ResultMessage = ResultMessage };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Angular**

```
self.submitEdit = function () {
        var updateRecordHeader = RecordServices.updateRecordHeader(self.header)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            self.header = response.data.Model;
            self.header.ResultMessage = response.data.ResultMessage;
        }, function errorCallback(response) { toastr.error(response.statusText); });
    }
```

Comment: Which property contains `DateTime` type? What you see is tick value of the actual `DateTime` struct, it's serialized in number of milliseconds since epoch (1970/01/01). You can create a function to return it as proper JS `Date` object.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto record.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Date(1545062400000)/` is known as date ticks using UNIX timestamp format since [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) "epoch" (January 01, 1970), which cannot be directly consumed as JS `Date` object without converting it first. The reason behind usage of the ticks is JSON format doesn't have specific representation for `DateTime` struct when serialized to plain strings (see [this reference](https://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html)).

You can create a custom function to convert ticks into JS `Date` object:

```
function toJSDate(value) {
   var regex = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
   var results = regex.exec(value);
   var date = new Date(parseFloat(results[1])); // or parseInt
   return date;
}
```

Or even simpler without regex by picking numeric values directly like this:

```
function toJSDate(value) {
   var date = new Date(parseFloat(value.substring(6))); // or parseInt
   return date;
}
```

Then use that function for ticks-to-date conversion:

```
// example
var header = response.data.Model;
var dateObject = toJSDate(header.Date);

// assign date object afterwards
```

Note that you may need to create another object structure which resembles `response.data.Model` but using server-side `Date` property with JS date object.

As an alternative you may create a getter-only `string` property which uses `ToString()` to convert `DateTime` value into desired string representation, then use it inside JS.

**Side note:**

Avoid using viewmodel property name which exactly matches built-in JS function names & objects (i.e. [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)) for clarity.

Related issues:

[How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

[Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)